# Telethon duplicates messages when forwarding

Tags: python, duplicates, telethon

My script is listening to a few chats for specified keywords. And when there is a match, it sends it to chat with the report. But I have a bug with duplicating messages in report chat when my script is running on the remote server. And I can't recreate that bug on the local machine.

```
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)
chats = []
for t in task_list:
    chats.extend(t['chats_to_listen'])

message_ids = []


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chats))
async def handle(event):
    m_obj = event.message
    m = event.message.to_dict()

    print('=== if id in sents ids', m['id'] in message_ids)
    if m['id'] in message_ids:
        print('=== DUPLICATE', m)
    else:
        for task in task_list:
            for key in task['keywords']:

                if key in m['message']:
                    print('=== message', m['message'])
                    chat_match = set(task['chats_to_listen']) & set(m['to_id'].values())
                    if chat_match:
                        chat_for_report_name = task['chat_to_report']
                        # await m_obj.forward_to(chat_for_report_name)
                        await client.forward_messages(chat_for_report_name, m_obj, list(chat_match)[0])

                        print(f'=== MESSAGE {m["id"]} SENT!')
                        message_ids.append(m['id'])
                        # time.sleep(2)
                        break
            else:
                continue
            break

        print('=== IDS SENT', message_ids)


print('Running')
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
print('Stopped')
```

I've tried `forward_to` method also, with the same result.

I'll be glad for any piece of advice. Thanks.

Comment: > when my script is running on remote server –

Maybe you're accidentally running the code twice?

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of this, but this duplication happens only in one chat (I have two, one for tests).

Comment: Lonami, you were right! So embarrassing! I forgot do shut it down on dev server. Facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to shut my app down on dev server :(